# Дешифрация письма

Tags: java, криптография

Возникла проблема с дешифрацией письма с помощью  закрытого ключа.

Вот код  процедуры дешифрации:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.Key;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.ContentType;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import net.suberic.crypto.EncryptionKeyManager;
import net.suberic.crypto.EncryptionManager;
import net.suberic.crypto.EncryptionUtils;
    public  static  void main (String arg[]){
        try {

            filein= "****";
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(filein);

            File fin= new File (filein);

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(null, fileIn);        

            String cryptotype = EncryptionManager.checkEncryptionType(message);
            if (cryptotype==null){
                errstring = "Сообщение не зашифровано";
                //удаляем файл
                if (fin.exists()){
                    fin.delete();
                };
                return;
            };
            certpassw = "****";
            certalias = "*****";
            certfilepath = "****";

            EncryptionUtils cryptoUtils = EncryptionManager.getEncryptionUtils(EncryptionManager.SMIME);

            EncryptionKeyManager keyMgr = cryptoUtils.createKeyManager();

            char[] smimePw = new String( certpassw).toCharArray();

            File _filepk12 = new File(certfilepath);
            if (_filepk12 == null) {
                errstring = "Не найден файл сертификата шифрования";
                // удаляем файл

                if (fin.exists()){
                    fin.delete();
                }
                return;
            };

            keyMgr.loadPrivateKeystore(new FileInputStream(_filepk12), smimePw);

            MimeMessage decryptedMsg = null;

            Key privateKey = keyMgr.getPrivateKey(certalias, smimePw);

            decryptedMsg = cryptoUtils.decryptMessage(null, message, privateKey);
            System.out.println(decryptedMsg.getContent().toString());

        }catch (Exception err){
            errstring = err.getMessage();
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

На строке:

```
decryptedMsg = cryptoUtils.decryptMessage(null, message, privateKey);
```

возникает следующая ошибка:

> Exception in thread "AgentThread: JavaAgent" 
>   java.lang.InstantiationError: org.bouncycastle.cms.RecipientId at
>   net.suberic.crypto.bouncycastle.SMIMEEncryptionUtils.decryptMessage(SMIMEEncryptionUtils.java:111)

Версия java: 1.6. Используем следующие библиотеки:

```
bcmail-jdk16-146.jar
bcprov-jdk16-146.jar
javamail-crypto_060622.jar
mail-1.4.1.jar
javamail-crypto-bouncycastle-smime_060622.jar
```

На локале код работает работает корректно, а вот  на сервере (ОС - Linux) возникает указанная выше ошибка.

полный лог ошибки:

> Exception in thread "AgentThread: JavaAgent" 
>   java.lang.InstantiationError: org.bouncycastle.cms.RecipientId
>   at net.suberic.crypto.bouncycastle.SMIMEEncryptionUtils.decryptMessage(SMIMEEncryptionUtils.java:111)
>   at ReadMessage_Class.main(Unknown Source)
>   at JavaAgent.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
>   at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
>   at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема.

---

Данная процедура вызывается из шедульного агента Notes/Domino. Указанные выше библиотеки мы вложили в директорию /jvm/lib/ext на сервере Domino. Также в java.security добавили провайдер BouncyCastle. У агента проставлены полномочия Allow Restricted operations.

Comment: покажите полный лог ошибки и импорты

Comment: Импорты: 
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.Key;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.ContentType;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import net.suberic.crypto.EncryptionKeyManager;
import net.suberic.crypto.EncryptionManager;
import net.suberic.crypto.EncryptionUtils;


Полный лог ошибки:

Comment: полный лог ошибки:
Exception in thread "AgentThread: JavaAgent" 
java.lang.InstantiationError: org.bouncycastle.cms.RecipientId
at net.suberic.crypto.bouncycastle.SMIMEEncryptionUtils.decryptMessage(SMIMEEncryptionUtils.java:111)
at ReadMessage_Class.main(Unknown Source)
at JavaAgent.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: в вопрос добавьте а то тут непонятно ничего

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я же говорю: "код представленный вами для Lotus Notes не предназначен".

1. Класс лотусового Java агента должен наследоваться от AgentBase
2. Класс лотусового Java агента не использует метод main(), метод должен называться NotesMain(). См. [help Domino Designer](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EXAMPLES_COMPILING_AND_RUNNING_JAVA.html) там всё очень подробно расписано. Должно быть что-то вроде этого:

```
import lotus.domino.*;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

  public void NotesMain() {

    try {
      Session session = getSession();
      AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();

      // (Your code goes here) 

    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: И отметьте в свой свойствах агента "Compile Java code with debugging information" - информация об ошибке будет более понятной.

Comment: И порпробуйте в файле **java.policy** в секции grant добавить строку **permission java.security.AllPermission;**. Сервер, конечно, после этого надо перезагрузить.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по ошибке вы пытаетесь запустить это в среде Lotus Notes, но код представленный вами для Lotus Notes не предназначен. Поясните, пожалуйста, как и где вы это запускаете, куда кладёте перечисленные вами библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

Совершенно очевидно, что проблема в `CLASSPATH` вы вызываете код из оболочки Notes/Domino и при запуске форка/шелла где-то теряется значение `CLASSPATH`. Надо как-то исхитриться и добавить CLASSPATH показывающий где лежат библиотеки или же найти куда смотрит `CLASSPATH` шелла и туда посадить криптобиблиотеку *Bouncy Castle*

Answer (score 0):

Всем доброго дня и спасибо за ваши ответы.

Решил проблему следующим образом:

1. Использовал  вместо  bcmail-jdk16-146.jar и bcprov-jdk16-146.jar следующий набор библиотек: bcmail-jdk14-138.jar и bcprov-jdk14-138.jar;
2. вынес указанный код  в отдельный класс в  java-библиотеку и теперь агент вызывает соответствующий метод класса:

Comment: Наверное ваш сервер версии 7.Х-8.0, там Java версий 1.4-1.5, соответственно использовать можно только bcmail-jdk14-138.jar и bcprov-jdk14-138.jar.  А bcmail-jdk16-146.jar и bcprov-jdk16-146.jar можно использовать на Domino 8.5 и выше, где уже Java 1.6.